# Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+. in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-gradle-plugin

We have added the appcompat-v7+ dependencies to eclipse and we are facing this error when trying to import flat-ui to the android project. 
Not sure why this is happening.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':sample'.

Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':sample:_debugCompile'.
Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+.
Required by:
com.github.eluleci:sample:2.0.2
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 0):

Go to the SDK Manager and install "Android Support Repository" in the "Extras" category.  Note, don't confuse this with "Android Support **Library**".